# Javascript: Simply change items in another select box?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm developing a registration page and wish to use JS to dynamically choose avatar selection based on gender. Here's what I have so far..

```
    <select name="gender">
       <option value="Male">Male
       </option>
       <option value="Female">Female
       </option>
    </select>
```

And that should update options in this based on gender:

```
    <select name="avatar">
       <option value="Trainer">Trainer
       </option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <img src="images/trainers/male/Trainer.gif" />
```

I can't wrap my head around example code or concepts, I just need an example of how to fill 2-3 values into the 'avatar' selectbox based on gender, female or male, also how can I make 'Trainer' part of 'Trainer.gif' become dynamic? based on the avatar they choose?

Answer (score 0):

First remove all elements in select box:

the form name is 'myform' and the name of the select box is 'master'

```
document.myform.master.options.length=0
```

then repopulate with new items: ( using the `Options(text, value, defaultSelected, selected)` object)

```
document.myform.master.options[0]=new Option("Sports", "sportsvalue", true, false)
document.myform.master.options[1]=new Option("Music", "musicvalue", false, false)
document.myform.master.options[2]=new Option("Movies", "moviesvalue", false, false)
```

This is a simple way you can dynamically change the select box's values.

You'll need to add an `if` statement to check the state of the `gender` select box and then you can update your second box

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, I use getelementbyid on a set ID and the select box returns null, not doesn't exist, just null.. Maybe i'll need to further look nto this.